# angularJS- initiate HTTP Call from a controller failed

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I am building a website using angularJS and PHP. Website has many pages like- Home, About Us etc.

So, I have created a common header for the website which I included in my HTML view like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="commonController.js"></script>
        <script src="homeController.js"></script>
        <script src="loginController.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header" ng-controller="CommonController"
             ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
        <div class="main" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the header (`header.html`) page looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <a  href="#/home">Home</a>
    <a  href="#/notifications" >{{vm.commonId}}</a>
</nav>
```

and header controller has a http call which fetches user id and I am trying to show this id as a label for one of the links mentioned above (`commonController.js`)

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.common', ['ngRoute'])

        .factory('myCommonService', function($http) {
            var baseUrl = 'api/';
            return {
                getBasicUserInfo:function() {
                    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getBasicUserInformation');
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('CommonController', function($scope, $routeParams, myCommonService) {
            var vm = this;      
            myCommonService.getBasicUserInfo().success(function(data) {
                vm.commonId = data.id;
            }); 
        });
})();
```

But when I navigate through pages, header remains same. So, I'm not able to initiate that http call. There are many pages in my website.

Can this be done? I'm pretty much new to this platform.

Route (`app.js`)

```
(function() {

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'myApp.login',
        'myApp.home',
        'myApp.common'
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'loginView.html',      
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'homeView.html',       
            controllerAs: 'vm'          
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);
})();
```

P.S: I excluded other pages to reduce complexity and make my query easy to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: I use `ui-router` which offers many more feature than `routeProvider` and your problem can be solved easily. This is not a solution for you but I thought it might help you.

Comment: Why are you doing `(function() {})()` in your files?

Comment: New to this. Is it wrong? @Chrillewoodz

Comment: @SajeevC if you were to introduce any variables or functions in the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) scope it would be worth doing but as it stands right now, they are redundant; everything you're doing is chained from the global `angular` variable

Comment: What Phil said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me all that is missing is letting the template know the scoped alias for the controller

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="CommonController as common"
     ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
```

and in `header.html`

```
<a href="#/notifications">{{common.commonId}}</a>
```

**Note** that I've used `common` instead of `vm` as some of your routes are using `vm` and it's best to avoid conflicts.

---

If you want to trigger an update on page navigation (ie, route change), change your `CommonController` to this

```
.controller('CommonController', function($scope, myCommonService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var update = function() {
        myCommonService.getBasicUserInfo().then(function(res) {
            ctrl.commonId = res.data.id;
        });
    };
    update();

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', update);
});
```

Comment: yeah.it shows the value but the http call getBasicUserInfo() is initiated only for the first time (when I load the website). Afterward when I navigate between pages, it doesn't get called. Think like, the variable's value changes (like notification count or something), so I have to check this call everytime @Phil

Comment: so, when a new notification comes, the variable value gets updated. So, I gotta check this call on every page...which I am not able to do as the header remains same for all page. @Phil

Comment: @SajeevC what should be the trigger for updating the notification? You can poll automatically using `$interval` or you could update manually given certain events. Which should it be?

Comment: @SajeevC I've updated my answer to include an example of the latter. If you want to use `$interval` instead, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
.when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'loginView.html', 
        resolve: function(){ //your code here }
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

instead of getting it from the controller

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue might be that the include can't read the controller, so instead try this:

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="CommonController as vm">
  <a  href="#/home">Home</a>
  <a  href="#/notifications" >{{vm.commonId}}</a>
</nav>
```

Note that you're also missing the `controllerAs` syntax so I added that.

And remove `ng-controller` from here:

```
<div class="header" ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: `ng-include` compiles the template with the current scope so the issue is definitely not to do with your first point

Comment: @Phil Not sure about that, because I've had issues with this before. I'm gonna see if I can dig up my old question about it.